# Custom Theme problems

Tags: magento2, theme, development

I just started to create a custom theme having as parent Magento/blank no when I try to deploy static-content I get `variable @addto-color is undefined`. How to debug this issue.

static structure

```
Vendor
--Theme
---web
----css
-----source
------- _themes.less //empty no css yet
------- _extend.less //empty no css yet
```

theme is registered and when I run  `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` fails with

```
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Vendor/theme/de_DE/css/styles-l.less
variable @addto-color is undefined
```

looking  on https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-theme everything looks the same as my theme but on deploy no variables getting inherited

Comment: Please share your code here

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure you are in developer mode:**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Delete all files/folders in:

```
pub/static/frontend
var/view_preprocessed

rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

then deploy your language specifically:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

set file permissions of pub folder and sub-directories to 755:

```
find pub -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: already made it couple of times, I think is a symlink issue

Comment: try renaming theme source folder to _source and then delete files & re-run deploy command

Comment: made it couple of times

Comment: Ensure you are in developer mode: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: Also try changing permissions of pub folder and all subdirectories to 755:
find pub -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Comment: thank you for help but still fighting with the same problem. I'm quite new to magento2 but I did not get the idea behind how to override a parent theme.

Comment: Try following instructions here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/109639/5880